# Searching in HashSet

Tags: java, search, generics, collections

I have 2 HashSet

```
Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> secondSet= new HashSet<String>();
```

Suppose

firstSet contains String as `[A-ABC,B-BCD,C-CDE,D-DEF,L-POK]`;

secondSet contains String as `[A,B,C,D,L,K,M]`;

Can i split each elements within firstSet like [A,B,C] without `for loop` and then do

```
firstSet.contains(secondSet);
```

or is their any appropriate way for doing this ?

Comment: Do you want to get all elements of firstSet, that contain a subset in secondSet? What should be your desired output?

Comment: @Rohit the output is to get all the elements present in second set from first set as [A,B,C,D,L]. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Hi Rohit...yes actually i wanted to get all elements of firstSet, that contain a subset in secondSet. Is their any way to achieve this using Collections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make firstSet instead a Map.

```
final Map map<String, String> = new HashMap<String, String();
map.put("A", "ABC");
map.put("B", "BCD");
...


map.keySet().containsAll(secondSet);
```

If that doesn't address your issue, perhaps you could explain in a bit more detail what you're trying to accomplish. There is no way to act on every element of a set without walking through every element of the set.

Comment: output is to get all the elements present in second set from first set such as [A,B,C,D,L].Can we still do it with a HashSet and not using HashMap?Is it Possible?

Comment: None of the elements in your second set are present in your first set. If you want to parse the contents of your first set to see if the elements start with the elements in the second set, then you have to look at every entry yourself.